# Is $\lambda (n/d)$ is also multiplicative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, liouville-function

Let $\lambda$ denote the Liouville $\lambda $- function. We know that $\lambda$ is multiplicative if we define it for integers $n$.

It is defined here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3245975/edit

Is the following function also multiplicative?
$$\sum_{d|n} \lambda(n/d) 2^{\omega(d) }?$$

**$\omega(n):=$** is the distinct prime divisors of $n$.

If so, why? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: @ThomasShelby ... I have included them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't your function the [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function#Convolution) of two multiplicative functions, and as such multiplicative itself?

---

**Proof** Let $f, g$ be two multiplicative functions. Let $m, n$ coprime integers. Then a divisor of $m n$ is of the form $d e$, where $d \mid m$ and $e \mid n$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{d \mid m, e \mid n} f(m n / d e) g(d e)
&=
\sum_{d \mid m, e \mid n} f(m/d) f(n /e) g(d) g( e)
\\&=
\left(\sum_{d \mid m} f(m/d) g(d)\right)
\cdot
\left(\sum_{e \mid n} f(n /e)g( e)\right)
.
\end{align}

Comment: I do not know that Dirichlet convolution is multiplicative ..... Do you have a proof?

Comment: so this is the answer of my question ?

Comment: Yes, I would say.